# Match path in classPath to path in resource folder in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to load all files that matches a regular expression, and then to delete them. I use this:

```
private static Resource[] loadResources(String relativePath) throws IOException {
    ClassLoader cl = FileUtils.class.getClassLoader();
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
    return resolver.getResources(relativePath);
}
```

This returns all files matching the regular expression

```
private List<String> getPathFromResources(Resource[] resources) {
    return Arrays.stream(resources)
            .map(this::parseUri)
            .filter(uri -> !uri.getPath().isEmpty())
            .map(URI::getPath)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private URI parseUri(Resource resource) {
    try {
        return resource.getURI();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(String.format("Resource %s cannot be loaded: %s", resource, e.getMessage()));
    }
    return URI.create("");
}
```

This returns their path

```
private List<String> getRelativeFiles(String relativePath) {
    try {
        Resource[] resources = loadResources(relativePath);
        return getPathFromResources(resources);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(String.format("Loading relative files with pattern : %s failed with error: %s", relativePath, e.getMessage()));
    }

    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

And this aggregates it. Now that I have list of all files that match the regular expression, I want to delete them. However the problem is, the path retrieved is in /target folder, which means deleting them is useless. However all files are also located in /resource folder. Since the `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` looks for files in classpath it's obvious it will find the path in /target folder, however is there any way to match that path in /target to their original location in /resource folder?

Comment: Things that are written/deleted are not really resources and you should probably treat them as files

Comment: however user can generate some files in test that gets stored in test-resources, processed, and then deleted

Comment: Such files should not be created in test-resources, but in the temporary folder of your file system.